# Possible to stop MDB in Weblogic 8.x?

Tags: jboss-mdb, weblogic8.x

Is it possible to programatically stop an MDB from listening to a queue in Weblogic 8.1?

I know this can be done in JBoss and later versions of Weblogic but I wasn't sure if it's possible in 8.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with Weblogic 9.x and Weblogic 10.x through the `MessageDrivenEJBRuntimeMBean` that exposes suspend/resume methods (see [BEA WebLogic Server 9.0 API Reference](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/javadocs_mhome/weblogic/management/runtime/MessageDrivenEJBRuntimeMBean.html) or [WebLogic Server 10.3 API Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/javadocs_mhome/weblogic/management/runtime/MessageDrivenEJBRuntimeMBean.html)) as explained in this [Thread: Suspending/Pausing a MDB's Consumption Programmatically](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=916987&tstart=0). AFAIK, this feature has been introduced in version 9.0 and I don't know if it was backported to 8.1 (in a service pack or as a patch). You might want to check this with <strike>BEA</strike>Oracle support.

Comment: I believe it was not backported.  Not totally positive but I can't find any mention of it in any documentation.

Comment: It may be available as a CR. Contact the support.

Answer (score 0):

You can undeploy the application that contains your MDB. You can use WLST to do that.