# Start stop JMS Message Listener

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jms, message-driven-bean

I have written two classes a JMS Message sender and JMS Message Listener class which are required to interact with SonicMQ which is configured on other system which is not in my control. I need to send JMS messages to a particular Queue and receive JMS Messages from Other Queue. Both the queues are configured on other server using SonicMQ.

Now I can invoke JMS sender class by creating an instance where ever required.

But how can I start my JMS Message Listener which implements MessageDrivenBean, MessageListener? I gone through some documentation where we need to configure in ejb-jar.xml. But I can I have control over its listening?

Also, do we need to do any configuration in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml as server is not in my control?

Comment: I am sorry, some how I got the wrong tag added to my question. I just edited. Thanks for your attention

Comment: I think you can find an answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532010/possible-to-stop-mdb-in-weblogic-8-x

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Foreign server in weblogic to connect to SonicMQ. Just do the configuration and weblogic will take care in connecting with SonicMQ.

Comment: Would be helpful to provide what kind of config was used to fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry I didn't login for long time. The configuration to be made is well documented in Oracle docs. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/jms_modules/foreign_servers/ConfigureForeignServers.html